# iOS play file from iTunes library and modify samples on the run

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

So i am currently starting to develop a iOS app that will need to play audio files from iTunes library and modify audio stream with custom DSP effect that needs to modify RAW data.... I am still trying to decide if i am going to go with swift or objective-c...

I know how to access iTunes library using MediaPlayer framework, but i need a simple way to modify RAW audio data while playing and then play the modified stream back.... So the question is how can i modify the stream and then play it back, and if i use other framework than MediaPlayer framework to play songs with my DSP will my app pass the apple review?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what AudioUnits are for. You can start here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiounit